# What is the grand partition function of a single fermion in contact with a thermal and particle reservoir?

Tags: thermodynamics

If we have a fermion system consisting of a single-particle state in contact with a thermal and particle reservoir with allowed microstates with energy $E_i$ and occupancies $N_i$ what is the grand partition function?

$$Z_G = \sum_i e^{\beta(\mu N_i - E_i)}$$

Since the occupancy $N_i$ can only be 0 or 1 I initially just considered the series simplifies down to
$$Z_G = \sum_i (e^{\beta(\mu - E_i)} + e^{-\beta E_i})$$

But then I considered that when the occupancy is zero surely the energy is also zero meaning the partition function would be

$$Z_G = e^0 + \sum_i e^{\beta(\mu - E_i)}$$

But then I am not sure whether this is correct as it may be when the occupancy is 1 the energy is always the same.

Which of these options is correct/incorrect and why?

Answer (score 0):

A "single" fermion does not sound like a grand partition function. Assuming distinguishable states labeled by $i$ and a reservour so that there can be *more than one* particle presen, you have
$$
Z=\prod_i (1+ e^{\beta(\mu-E_i)}).
$$

Comment: I may have worded my question poorly/incorrectly I have updated the question

Comment: I still do not know what you mean by distinguishing a "singl- particle state" from the "microstates" since it seems that each $E_i$ is  an eigen energy of the single-particle Hamiltonian  that is being converted to a many-particle Hamiltonian by second-quantization.   Thus the $|E_i\rangle $ are all "single-particle states"